# How do I propagate NULL values in a custom expression?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I currently have a query on the following form:

```
SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN <column> IS NOT NULL THEN <expression>
        ELSE NULL
    AS <new_column>,
    CASE
        WHEN <other_column> IS NOT NULL THEN <other_expression>
        ELSE NULL
    AS <new_other_column>,
    -- etc...
```

I'm thinking that it must be possible to rewrite the `CASE` statements as something that's easier to read, with less boilerplate.

I could do it with an `IIF`:

```
IIF(<column> IS NOT NULL, <expression>, NULL) AS <new_column>
```

but that still leaves both `IS NOT NULL` and `NULL` there.

Is there some construct `FOO` that would let me say

```
FOO(<nullcheck_expression>, <result_expression>)
```

and have that return the same thing as `IIF(<nullcheck_expression> IS NOT NULL, <result_expression>, NULL)`?

Comment: So you want [the opposite of `ISNULL`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19242782/is-there-a-opposite-function-to-isnull-in-sql-server-to-do-is-not-null)? I'm afraid that there is no other way than your `CASE`. But i find it very readable.

Comment: Look into the NULLIF() function.

Comment: I was also trying to come up with a clever solution using `COALESCE` but was unable to do so.

Comment: @TabAlleman: i don't see how `NULLIF` would help to simplify this.

Comment: Maybe it can't, but he's simplified his code for this question, obviously, so in his real situation, maybe it can.

Comment: @TabAlleman: but how? You have to specify the value that should be treated as `NULL` in the `NULLIF` function. But in this case `NULL` is simply `NULL` and **all other** values are `expression`.

Comment: Do you really need an explicit function? - The `ELSE NULL` is redundant, given that an [unmatched case will project NULL](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4626/314291) in any event

Comment: @TimSchmelter: Yes, the opposite of `ISNULL` is a good description of what I want. The `CASE` statements are less readable when there's ten of them in a row and the´<expression>`s are longer :)

Comment: @TabAlleman: Actually, except for substituting `<expression>` for the real expressions that I select, I haven't changed or simplified anything. There's literally a bunch of `CASE` statements where there's exactly one `WHEN` clause, where that `WHEN` clause checks a column for `NULL`, and where the `ELSE` clause returns `NULL`.

Comment: @StuartLC: That's actually quite nice, and would help reduce the wall-of-boilerplate, but would obviously obfuscate the code a little to someone who doesn't know that. I'll see how it looks with a comment about it on top... ;)

Comment: Well if you just want to make the code shorter and more human-readable, you could always write a UDF that does what you want.

Comment: @TomasLycken, can you show an example of <expression>?

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri, here's the longest IIF that I used: `IIF(pcc.OrganizationNumber IS NOT NULL,
  LEFT(CAST(ABS(CAST(CAST(NEWID() AS varbinary) AS int)) AS varchar(max)), 6) + '-' + LEFT(CAST(ABS(CAST(CAST(NEWID() AS varbinary) AS int)) AS varchar(max)), 4),
  NULL) AS OrganizationNumber`. The first part is always `<column_name> IS NOT NULL`.

Comment: @TabAlleman: Sure, a UDF could do this. The question was also meant as "If I wrote a UDF for this, would I re-implement functionality that's already built-in?"

Comment: @TomasLycken, i.e. `WHEN <column> IS NOT NULL THEN <expression>` column is not participating in expression. Am I right?

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri: Yes, at least for the cases I have now that seems to be the case.

Comment: @TomasLycken, sorry, one more. What are types of columns and expressions? Are they always strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the answer to the question I posed is "no, there is no such function built-into SQL Server".

Instead, I ended up using the [`IIF`-function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213574(v=sql.120).aspx), which, in conjunction with a few well-placed line breaks, is still much better than the original `CASE` statements. It's kind-of annoying to have `IS NOT NULL` sprinkled everywhere, but since they are all keywords that both MS SQL Management Studio and Visual Studio highlight in low-contrast gray, I can live with that.

Comment: `IIF` will be translated to a `CASE` statement. If you think that it makes your query more readable it's fine. I prefer to write sql that works in most rdbms. `IIF` works only in SQL-Server 2012 and newer.

Answer (score 0):

You can try taking advantage of `NULL` behavior in SQL by concatenating the `<expression>` value with the `<column>` value.

```
SELECT LEFT(<expression> + <column>, n)
```

where `n` is the length of the `<expression>` value. If the `<column>` value is `NULL`, then it will concatenate to `NULL`, and the `LEFT` function will return a `NULL`. Otherwise, it will just take the `<expression>` from your `<expression> + <column>` concatenation.

Comment: This is a good idea, but the result of `<expression>` is not fix-length, so I would have to either repeat it, or define an UDF for it - and in the latter case, an `IIF` or `NULLIF` construct is probably easier.

Answer (score 0):

You can drop the `ELSE NULL` part which helps a bit:

```
 CASE WHEN <column> IS NOT NULL THEN <expression> END AS <new_column>
```

I also reformatted to a single line to take less vertical space.

Answer (score 0):

If you confirm that both columns and expressions are of `varchar` types then here is a little trick:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE(v varchar(10))

INSERT INTO @t VALUES('test'), (NULL)

SELECT LEFT(v, 0) + 'your expression' AS ExpressionResult
FROM @t
```

Output:

```
ExpressionResult
your expression
NULL
```

Explanation: if column contains some data it will return `LEFT(v, 0) = ''` and if it is null then it will return `LEFT(v, 0) = NULL`. This is shortest solution I've been able to find.